# Converting DNs to radiance and reflectance for Planet Labs Imagery

Tags: reflectance, planet

I am trying to convert pixel DNs to reflectance from a Planet BGRN Analytic Scene (from 2016, I can't tell what level it is processed to).  However, I can't find info on the exo-atmospheric irradiance of the 4 bands.  Is this available somewhere?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE kmc44. Please provide links to data you are referring to.

Comment: From https://www.planet.com/products/satellite-imagery/files/1611.09_Spec_Sheet_Combined_Imagery_Product_Letter_DraftV3.pdf I'd say that there is no fixed relationship unless you have RapidEye, in which case see Section 6.4.2 of that document.

Answer (score 5):

If the file contains "DN" in the name then it is not scaled radiance and there is are no coefficients available to scale to scale to exo-atmospheric irradiance.

If the product is the "analytic" asset from the PSScene4Band type the filename should include "_3B_AnalyticMS" and it is scaled radiance.

If the product is the "analytic" asset from the PSOrthoTile type the filename should include "_BGRN_Analytic" and it is scaled radiance.

If you have a scaled radiance product, you can multiple by 0.01 to convert the 16bit pixels values to watts per steradian per square meter (W/m²*sr*μm).

If you want to convert to convert to top of atmosphere reflectance, you will need to multiply by the value of the "reflectanceCoefficient" from the associated _metadata.xml file.  Note that you do not compose the radiometricScaleFactor (0.01) and the reflectanceCoefficient - just multiple the original pixels values from the analytic files by hte reflectanceCoefficient.  This ought to be covered page 32 of  https://www.planet.com/products/satellite-imagery/files/1611.09_Spec_Sheet_Combined_Imagery_Product_Letter_DraftV3.pdf or perhaps there is a more recent version that did not come up in my google search.

Comment: Thanks Frank.  This is exactly what I want to do.  I have the associated metadata.xml file -- is it the reflectance coefficient that I need (after I multiply by the radiometricScaleFactor)?

Comment: @kmc44, I updated my answer about with additional details.  It does not appear the normal external product docs cover this aspect yet, though added the value in the _metadata.xml file production a 2-3 months ago.